# Jquery slider django

Tags: jquery, html, django, rangeslider, form-fields

I cant get a rangeslider to working in Django. The rangeslider seems to work.

I want to store the answer from the form field 'QA1', retrieved by a rangeslider, in my database.

Any help is appreciated!

```
form: slider.html
<div class="slider">
<span class="amount" > </span>
<span id="amount" type="text" value="{{ form.QA1 }}"></span>                                
<div class="slider-range"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider").each(function() {

        $this = $(this);

        $(".slider-range", $this).slider({
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            values: [30],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {

               $(this).parent().find(".amount").html(  + ui.values[ 0 ]);
            }
            change: function( event, ui ) {
              $('#id_QA1').value(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $(".amount").html(  + $(".slider-range").slider("values", 0 ));
    });
});
</script>
```

Models.py:

```
class MyForm(models.Model): 
    QA1 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    QA2 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    QA3 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    QA4 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
```

forms.py

```
class MyFormForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Myform
        fields = ['QA1', 'QA2', 'QA3', 'QA4',
        ]

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(form=self)
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div('QA1', css_class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'), 
                Div('QA2', css_class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'), 
                Div('QA3', css_class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'), 
                Div('QA4', css_class='col-md-2 col-sm-2'), css_class='row'                                  
            ),
            Div(Submit('save', 'submit'), css_class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2'
            ),
```

Comment: I didn’t see a form anywhere in your post.  Where is the form that you are submitting to django?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I updated my question

Comment: I’m still not seeing a `form` in your HTML.  If you want to submit a form to django there has to be a `form` in the HTML.  Were you planning on using AJAX instead of a form post?